# mark text with keyboard in PDFView (pdf-tools) mode

Tags: pdf, mark

I've replaced `doc-view` mode with `pdf-tools`.

While it's easy to set a mark on a page with the mouse, how do you do it with the keyboard?

The readme mentions the feature.
"* Mark a region and kill the text from the PDF."

The closest I've gotten is marking the whole page with `M-x pdf-view-mark-whole-page`.

Comment: You can search the source code, you will find some keybinding definition.
Like: `(define-key map [down-mouse-1] 'pdf-view-mouse-set-region)`, and `(define-key map [M-down-mouse-1] 'pdf-view-mouse-set-region-rectangle)`, and `(define-key map [C-down-mouse-1] 'pdf-view-mouse-extend-region)`, `(when (eq (car e) 'drag-mouse-1)` etc. You can bind them to custom keybindings for yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would require some notion of a cursor, which is currently not implemented.  So marking by keyboard is not available (except the whole page).

Comment: How do you select the whole page?

Comment: I see, pdf-view-mark-whole-page

Comment: It can be achieved using avy. The file [pdf-avy-highlight.el](https://github.com/dalanicolai/dala-emacs-lisp/blob/master/pdf-avy-highlight.el) that can be found [here](https://github.com/dalanicolai/dala-emacs-lisp) uses avy to provide highlighting via the keyboard in pdf-tools.